# C++ weird usage of this?

Tags: c++

Not sure if what I am doing seems like a terrible design, but I am trying to do the following:

```
class c_a
{
public:
    void do_stuff(c_b *b)
    {
        b->move_x();
    }
};

class c_b
{
public:
    void call()
    {
        c_a a;
        a.do_stuff(this);
    }

    void move_x()
    {
        cout << "test";
    }
};

int main()
{
    c_b b;
    b.call();
}
```

I am getting compiler errors `syntax error : identifier 'c_b'`. How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every name before its usage shall be declared.

```
class c_a
{
public:
    void do_stuff( class c_b *b);
};

class c_b
{
public:
    void call()
    {
        c_a a;
        a.do_stuff(this);
    }

    void move_x()
    {
        cout << "test";
    }
};

void c_a::do_stuff( c_b *b)
{
    b->move_x();
}

int main()
{
    c_b b;
    b.call();
}
```